Is there any way to sign macro's of an XLSM file in silent mode, so that it can be automated using a pipeline
In order to sign macros of an .xlsm, following steps have to be performed .

Open the workbook that contains the macro project that you want to sign.
Press ALT+F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor.
In the Project Explorer, select the project that you want to sign.
On the Tools menu, click Digital Signature.

Do one of the following:
a) If you have not previously selected a digital certificate, or if you want to use another one, click Choose, select the certificate, and then click OK two times.
b) To use the current certificate, click OK.
ref: How do I code sign a macro project
These steps have to performed using Excel UI.
Question: Is there any way to sign macro's of an XLSM file in silent mode using .NET c#, so that it can be automated
